# Correct use of `recur` in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, tail-recursion

I'm trying to solve the [Count a Sequence](https://www.4clojure.com/problem/22) problem on [4Clojure](https://www.4clojure.com), but I can't work out what's wrong with my use of `recur`:

```
fn [s] (
    fn [t n] (
        if (empty t)
            n
            (recur (rest t) (+ n 1))
    ) s 0
)
```

It gives the following exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can only recur from tail position, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0)

But to me it seems that the call to `recur` *is* in a tail position for the inner function.  What am I missing?

Comment: The task doesn't state that should use `recur`, and while it's very good to know it, it's also considered to be lower-level building block. There are high-level functions, which you can use to solve this problem in a much more readable and idiomatic way.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

- Your parentheses are misplaced.
- You are using [`empty`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/empty) where you want [`empty?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/empty_q).

Parentheses

- The [`fn` special form](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28fn%20name?%20%5Bparams%2a%20%5D%20exprs%2a%29) for defining a function takes the shape
  `(fn name? [params* ] exprs*)` with the parentheses around it.
- Another level of parentheses applies the function `((fn [n] (* n n))
  3) => 9`.

Using `defn` instead of `fn` for the moment, we get

```
(defn l [s] 
  ((fn [t n] (if (empty? t) n (recur (rest t) (+ n 1))))
       s 0))
```

Then, for example,

```
(l ())
; 0
```

and

```
(l [1 2 3])
; 3
```

Comment: Hmm thanks.  Does moving parentheses make a difference to the meaning of the code, or just readability?  Changing `empty` to `empty?` doesn't fix it...  I'll read up the difference between `defn` and `fn`, although `defn` is not allowed in 4clojure solutions.

Comment: @Armand Moving parentheses changes the *structure* of the code, hence changes its meaning. I used `defn` instead of `fn` to separate the definition of the function from its use. Just change it back, and - if you prefer - drop the name `l`. I suppose I'm trying to say that your code was basically correct, apart from being nonsense :).

Comment: aha!  i thought you were objecting to the indentation, but actually you mean i'm missing a set of parentheses (I think!) :-)  works now and I feel a little stupid - thanks

Answer (score 3):

@Thumbnail is right -- your code will work just fine if you fix the placement of your parentheses (most importantly, you need to add a `(` before `(fn [t n] ...` and a corresponding `)` after `s 0`, in order to actually return the result of calling that function (the one that takes `t` and `n` as arguments) on the values `s` and `0`. Otherwise, you are returning the function itself.), and change `empty` to `empty?`.

If you wanted to simplify things a bit, you might consider using a `loop`/`recur` structure instead, like this:

```
(fn [s]
  (loop [t s, n 0]
    (if (empty? t)
      n
      (recur (rest t) (+ n 1)))))
```